# Visual Studio Analysis Services Extension not deploying tabular Measures

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssas, powerbi, ssas-tabular, ssdt-bi

I have a fairly simple tabular sales model (Customers, Products, Sales) deployed to a SSAS 2016 server in tabular mode and I have a few measures setup on the sales table, things like total value, total kgs, total units, but after deploying the model, they do not show up when connecting with Power BI.  Is there a setting that i might be missing somewhere that could be stopping the measure from showing up?

**Update**
One of the things I have tried, is to run the Create Script Task in SSMS to see if the measures get added as part of the SSAS Database create script and it appears that they are not there from that angle either.

Comment: Can you see them when you browse the measures from SSMS, or from excel? 
Be sure that they are not greyed out (means: hide from client tools) is activated. This however would mean that you can still see them from the create script task.

Comment: Nope. They are not visible in ssms i haven't explicitly set them to be hidden.

Comment: The deployement from Visual Studio to SSAS 2016 is not going well. Do you have some error messages when deploying?

Comment: From what i can see, it deploys without errors. I will try again when im at work in 8 hrs to see if there are any warnings or console output errors that i have missed.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out... I haven't deployed it just.  It was the separator between the naming of the measure and the formula that was the issue.  I just had the equal sign (=) instead of the colon equal (:=) which is what DAX is expecting. It wasn't until I tried removing the name and leaving the formula much like an Excel formula that the formula editor decided I had screwed up and fixed up my naming of the measure.  It was at this point that I found the issue with my naming without the colon.

The measures are now calculating as expected in VS and they now show up on the Tabular Model Explorer.

The odd thing though is that there were no errors at all to say that there was an issue.  The deploy just worked without any issues.  So that is one to watch when your measures don't show up.

**Update**
I have deployed to my on-premise 2016 server and the measures now show up.